# How to make a dependent mutation in react query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a mutate function which make POST request and receives `id` , after then I need Immediately call next mutation function to make  a purchase in accordance with this `id`, how do I make this ?

```
const mutation = useCreatePaymentMethodMutation();

const handleSubmit = async(values:any) {
  const form = await mutation.mutateAsync({
    values,
    hash
  })
  return form
}
```

`useCreatePaymentMethodMutation` is imported from @Hooks

```
const useCreatePaymentMethodMutation = () => {
 return useMutation(
    ({ values, accessHash }: { values: any; accessHash: string }) =>
      createPaymentMethodRequest(values, accessHash),
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        // usePayMutation(data.data, accessHash); error. I need to use data after 1st mutation in next 
        request
        console.log("on success data ", data);
      },
    }
  );
}
```

**UPD 1**

Here is my `usePayMutation` method

```
const usePayMutation = () => {
  return useMutation(({ data, id }: { data: any; id: string }) =>
    payRequest(data, id)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're 2 options for you to do it

**Option 1:**
In your `useCreatePaymentMethodMutation` hooks

```js
const useCreatePaymentMethodMutation = () => {
 const mutatePay = usePayMutation()
 return useMutation(
    ({ values, accessHash }: { values: any; accessHash: string }) =>
      createPaymentMethodRequest(values, accessHash),
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        mutatePay(data.id)
      },
    }
  );
}
```

**Option 2:**
In your `handleSubmit` function

```js
const mutatePay = usePayMutation()

const handleSubmit = (values:any) => {
  return mutation.mutateAsync({
    values,
    hash
  }).then(data=> mutatePay(data.id))
}
```

Comment: I have the following error ```An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')```

Comment: in 1st option ```This expression is not callable.
  Type 'UseMutationResult<AxiosResponse<any> | { isError: boolean; status: any; }, unknown, { data: any; id: string; }, unknown>' has no call signatures.```

Answer (score 4):

you would create two different mutations, and call them one after the other:

```
const createPayment = useCreatePaymentMethodMutation()
const otherMutation = useOtherMutation()

const handleSubmit = async(values:any) {
  try {
    const form = await createPayment.mutateAsync({
      values,
      hash
    })
    await otherMutation.mutateAsync(form.id)
  }
  catch(...)
}
```

Comment: ```Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')``` when i log form it is an object ```{ config, data, headers, request , status, statusText }``` so I was trying to put in ```otherMutation form.data```

Comment: if i put whole ```form``` , ```otherMutation.mutateAsync(form)``` then ```Argument of type 'AxiosResponse<any> | { isError: boolean; status: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ data: any; id: string; }'.```

Comment: thanks for the reply. 

do you have to try catch the result of a mutation?

it has a lot of nice error handling features like onError, isError, onSettled etc.